# Is there any reason to put user authentication farther down the chain instead at the middleware level in express?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

Is there **any reason** to put user authentication farther down the chain INSTEAD at the middleware level of express (i.e. `app.use(express.express.basicAuth(...)` )?

(It seems like there is no good reason to live outside of the middleware.)

Why I'm asking. I've gotten some inherited code where the previous programmer put user.auth in the controller.

So a call from the client follows this path:

```
 client  >>   

       middleware of express  >>   

           api_server (ROUTER passes on requests to proper CONTROLLER)  >>

                 api_server (CONTROLLER gets what it needs from DB)  >>

                      api_server (CONTROLLER sends response with data to VIEW on way  back to client)  >>

                                client happy ;D
```

(Please provide suggestions on how to make this question more precise if it's lacking somewhere. I'm getting up to speed on setting up an entire system.)'

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are targeting that specific route there is no reason to do this. You can even do url specific auth with global middleware as well. The following code is common in my applications.

```
app.use('/administrator/*', authMiddleware);
```

Comment: Good. I'm going to rip out the authenentication from the controller then and use the express middleware because, as you said, you can easily target specific routes with express. I'll just have the controllers focus on querying MongoDB. (I'll sit one this into evening to see if other thoughts come in.)

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Enome/6641fc2ae25fc48dc3ba) is how I keep sane routes. I try to keep my middleware as small as possible and generic where it makes sense. For example the data.one, data.many, ... is generic middleware that can query the database. Reason for this is so you limit the amount of custom middleware + tests you have to write. It's a process where you start with custom middleware, get annoyed by the quantity of tests you have to write and then you start abstracting it into reusable generic middleware.

Comment: You take advantage of the middleware; I think that is the smart way to go. How do you group? You mentioned data is for DB queries. Events is for? Also, you basically put all your routing into the middleware, with the final middleware going to a response module(general.render('grows/show')), right?

Comment: The events middleware massages the event data into what the template is expecting. It's a calendar app so events are an entity in the application. As for your second question: that is correct. After writing the same test to check if x middleware renders the correct view I came to the conclusion it's better to have a render middleware. This does mean that if you want to test if a route renders a certain view you need an extra test. Full route tests are complicated though with the amount of state and code forks you can have.

Comment: Great. I like the concept of render middleware.